# I need help with the documents that i should provide?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I applied twice for a UK visa and both were refused despite being born there. 
The first time was a child visitor visa i was 17 years old. I was going to visit my french citizen brother living in UK but I forgot to provide a key document which is a copy of his passport.

The second time was a standard visitor visa  I was 19 with both my parents (they both obtained their visas) i got a refusal and could not appeal , the reason of the refusal was that i provided a school certificate of the past year so there for i had no ties to my country , but i applied in mid summer during the summer break, registrations for the following year hadn't started yet so it was impossible to provide them a certificate of the upcoming academic year (i was still in high school)

So a year later now things changed i'n in university and want to apply for a third time i will be staying in a hotel and the key documents that i will provide are : my fathers bank statements , my university attendance certificate , hotel reservation and want to include a letter to the immigration officer explaining that I want to visit the UK to enjoy the festivities and that i might seem desperate to get to the UK but I have no intention to over stay or settle and that i want to visit as a tourist and that i have to comeback to pursue my studies.

So my question is should I provide the letter or not? My father told me it's too much blabla and will complicate things.

Also the question to why is your father paying for your trip? Should I say because I'm a student or give them a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 2):

> **should I provide the letter or not?**

There is nothing to be gained by including statements such as *"I have no intention to over stay or settle"*. By applying for a *visitor* visa, you have already communicated that.

I would only include things in additional attachments if those matters are *not* already covered elsewhere in the application form. You need to balance providing full information with making your application clear and easy to assess.

> **My father told me it's too much blabla and will complicate things.**

Advice to listen to your father is probably more often right than wrong. In this case I agree with your father.

> **["]why is your father paying for your trip?["] Should I say because I'm a student or give them a more detailed answer?**

Since it is not the case that all fathers planetwide give all their offspring free solo vacations to places like the UK during their student years, you probably do need to explain why your father is being so generous. Being a student is usually not by itself sufficient reason for parents to pay for expensive vacations.

> **the reason [for] the refusal was that [... I] had no ties to my country**

You also need to address this in your subsequent application.

> **I applied twice for a UK visa and both [applications] were refused**

If your read about similar cases here, you will see that the usual advice is that you are approaching [a situation where you will need professional help from a UK registered lawyer specialising in visa applications](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=refusal+tailspin).

I would take extreme care over every part of the application.